# How to remove delete link from admin manage fields ui

Tags: 7, forms, entities

I have created a new entity type and progamatically added the fields it requires. My issues is that on the Manage Fields UI (the same interfaced used for managing fields for basic pages/articles), in the operations column there is an option to delete the field. How do I remove prevent the delete link from appearing?

I have googled and looked at the FAPI documentation but don't see an option for this. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: With out of the box drupal you cannot control access specifically to that action. Possibly something exists in a contrib module that would allow you to, otherwise you would need custom code.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say you might consider exporting your created Entity to a feature. This way, if anything ever gets "deleted" by accident you can easily revert it with one command using drush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function will do one of two things - remove the link from the screen, or limit it's effect to doing nothing, depending on what you want to accomplish.

This will work on the Body of an Article - you will need to adjust names appropriately for the content type and field names.

Keep in mind however this will not prevent them from accessing the delete functionality using the url: example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/body/delete - you would need to either override the menu, use an access restriction module or something like [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to prevent users from manually deleting the field.

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'field_ui_field_overview_form' && $form['#bundle'] == 'article')
  {
    unset($form['fields']['body']['delete']);  // remove the link

    $form['fields']['body']['delete']['#href'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '#';  // make the link have no effect
  }
}
```